# implement more than one click listener on a button

Tags: android, events, routes, event-bubbling

I am working on an application that requires me to implement more than one click listener on a button. I am stuck. After some searching, I only came across a few hacks that can make this possible.

However in this case, some are not applicable since in my application, the logic is that if the button is clicked and the condition is met, then the second listener is called firing off another event.

This seems tricky. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you call the implementation of your second click listener whenever the first click listener is executed?

Comment: Why you need more than one click listener? Cannot you just put your logic inside one click listener and then call the appropriate code from there?

Comment: Thanks but when I place the logic in one click listener, one gets overridden over the other..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can meet your requirement using this:

set a global variable say `int condition_number=0;`

then,

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)
{    
     performThis(condition_number);
}

perforThis(int number)
{
   switch(number) 
   {
       case 1:
              //do some stuff for condition 1
              //set condition_number accordingly,relatively to what you want to perform next
              performThis(codition_number);
              break;

       case 2:
              //do some stuff for condition 2
              //set condition_number accordingly,relatively to what you want to perform next
              performThis(codition_number);
              break;

       case 3:
              //do some stuff for condition 3
              //set condition_number accordingly,relatively to what you want to perform next
              performThis(codition_number);
              break;

       default:
               //do something
               break;
   }
}
```

This way,you would be able to call different code snippets for different condition and repeatedly call them as you require without making conflict.

You can set a case to get out of the execution of this method by just putting break there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making another listener, just call different functions depending the conditions, from your one and only listener.

Comment: Shadow, could you please shed some more light? am really stuck on this for long time..

Comment: What I understood from your problem is that you want to perform different actions depending on some condition, when you press a button right? So my suggestion is in the listener just put switch conditions where for each condition you call a separate function which takes care of the entire logic you want to perform. In short keep the logic outside the listener and just the condition checking in the listener. Hope this helps.

Comment: Shadow, thanks for the advice, I am only wondering, what condition should I pass in the switch? excuse my clueless mind but I was thinking of using the view as condition then I remembered it would be useless as there is only one button view..please advise

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by shadow, you can do something like that:

your XML layout:

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/doStuff"
     android:onClick="doStuff" />
```

in your activity:

```
function void doStuff(View target) {
   listener1(target);
   listener2(target);
   ...
}

function void listener1(View target) {
   ...
}

function void listener2(View target) {
   ...
}
```

And then implement your multiple listeners in listener1, listener2, etc...